# Implement a method for ordered_vowel_words

Tags: ruby, algorithm

I've been going over some of the many coding interview questions. I was wondering about implementing an ordered_vowel words method.  I'm working on algorithm question to implement this method for purposes of the understanding algorithm. I have the below:

This method takes a string of lowercase words and returns a string with just the words containing all their vowels (excluding "y") in alphabetical order. Vowels may  be repeated (`"afoot"` is an ordered vowel word)

```
def ordered_vowel_words(str)
  words = str.split(" ")

  ordered_vowel_words = words.select do |word|
    ordered_vowel_word?(word)
  end

  ordered_vowel_words.join(" ")
end

def ordered_vowel_word?(word)
  vowels = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"]

  letters_arr = word.split("")
  vowels_arr = letters_arr.select { |l| vowels.include?(l) }

  (0...(vowels_arr.length - 1)).all? do |i|
    vowels_arr[i] <= vowels_arr[i + 1]
  end
end
```

I added the following test cases:

```
puts("\nTests for #ordered_vowel_words")
puts("===============================================")
    puts "ordered_vowel_words(\"amends\") == \"amends\": "  + (ordered_vowel_words("amends") == "amends").to_s
    puts "ordered_vowel_words(\"complicated\") == \"\": "  + (ordered_vowel_words("complicated") == "").to_s
    puts "ordered_vowel_words(\"afoot\") == \"afoot\": "  + (ordered_vowel_words("afoot") == "afoot").to_s
    puts "ordered_vowel_words(\"ham\") == \"ham\": "  + (ordered_vowel_words("ham") == "ham").to_s
    puts "ordered_vowel_words(\"crypt\") == \"crypt\": "  + (ordered_vowel_words("crypt") == "crypt").to_s
    puts "ordered_vowel_words(\"o\") == \"o\": "  + (ordered_vowel_words("o") == "o").to_s
    puts "ordered_vowel_words(\"tamely\") == \"tamely\": "  + (ordered_vowel_words("tamely") == "tamely").to_s
```

What is the runtime analysis for this one?

Why is it true that we can get O(m)O(m) runtime for mm function calls.

I appreciate your explanation for this. thank you.

Comment: I was able to solve it. thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This method is short and should be reasonably readable :

```
def ordered_vowel_words(str)
  str.split(" ").select{|w| ordered_vowel_word?(w) }.join(" ")
end

def ordered_vowel_word?(word)
  vowels = word.scan(/[aeiou]/)
  vowels == vowels.sort
end
```

It might not be very efficient to sort an array just to check it's already sorted, so here's an alternative :

```
def ordered_vowel_word?(word)
  word.scan(/[aeiou]/).each_cons(2).all?{ |vowel1, vowel2| vowel1 <= vowel2 }
end
```

With this method, the whole complexity should be `O(n)`, `n` being the number of characters in `str`.

Complexity cannot be any better, because the whole string needs to be parsed at least once to find the vowels. There might be faster implementations, though.

Comment: Nice solution. You commented on my now-deleted answer, saying you didn't understand it. Perhaps that's because it was incorrect. I made some edits, but it still isn't correct, and even if I fixed it, it would be neither useful nor interesting. So, off with its head!

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're just using the solution provided by App Academy for this question. When preparing for these interview questions, it's important that you try to solve them all yourself - they won't ask you these exact questions, but variations of the same logic (breaking up data structures, applying some methods to them, and comparing results or building new responses based on the input.)

So, if you're serious about applying, don't look at the solutions. I also advise trying to find a mentor.

Now, on to your question.

```
require 'benchmark'

def ordered_vowel_words(str)
  words = str.split(" ")

  ordered_vowel_words = words.select do |word|
    ordered_vowel_word?(word)
  end

  ordered_vowel_words.join(" ")
end

def ordered_vowel_word?(word)
  vowels = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"]

  letters_arr = word.split("")
  vowels_arr = letters_arr.select { |l| vowels.include?(l) }

  (0...(vowels_arr.length - 1)).all? do |i|
    vowels_arr[i] <= vowels_arr[i + 1]
  end
end

puts Benchmark.measure {ordered_vowel_words("amends")}
puts Benchmark.measure {ordered_vowel_words("complicated")}
puts Benchmark.measure {ordered_vowel_words("afoot")}
puts Benchmark.measure {ordered_vowel_words("ham")}
puts Benchmark.measure {ordered_vowel_words("crypt")}
puts Benchmark.measure {ordered_vowel_words("o")}
puts Benchmark.measure {ordered_vowel_words("tamely")}
```

Refer to here for some easy benchmarking tools: https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/benchmark/rdoc/Benchmark.html

Comment: What do you want to achieve with those benchmarks? They run in a few microseconds, so they won't have any statistical value.

Comment: @EricDuminil agreed, but the OP asked for benchmarks. Frankly, I think we've all sunk too much time in such a low effort question. All the code is literally copied and pasted, testing too.